# how to hide value label under input type="range" element

Tags: html, slider

I spent such a long time trying to figure this out and I can not find anything on google about it but how do you hide or remove the value label that lies under the input type="range" (slide bar) element that shows the current value of the slide bar.

If you don't know what I am talking about since I understand that this label does not always show up with the html slide bar but in chrome (Version 54.0.2840.98) and safari (Version 10.0.1) at least it always shows up in my case. For example, this SINGLE line:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100">
```

always outputs:

[image]

That number under the slide bar is what I want to get rid of! Please help I'm hopeless!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a website with a very good explanation for you how to hide it as well as customize if necessary!
http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html

Comment: thanks for the reply but I have literally already visited this site while searching for an answer and I still can not get it to disappear even though I can style the slide bar. I also can even set the slider's display to display:none; and I will still be able to see the number!

Answer (score 0):

I did not entirely figure out why this label appears and how you exactly get rid of it; HOWEVER, this label inherits its style from its parent element (in my case a div element) so all you have to do is to set the parent element's `color` to `color: transparent;` and done, no more pesky label.

I hope this helps someone!

**EDIT**:

Actually it turns out for some reason a `<span>` element was automatically being created with the slide bar that displays its value so you could also loop through the the parents elements and remove it from the doc there if you choose so.